# Minimum permissions to modify a work item template

Tags: tfs

If I'm trying to configure TFS 2008 for minimum necessary permissions, what permissions are required in order for a user to be able to modify a work item template?  I tried just granting "View project-level information" and "Edit project-level information", but that was not sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty certain the user needs project admin permissions to modify workitem templates.

Comment: Look's like it does not work. I'm project admin, and when I modify Bug Workitem description it shows error "You don't have enough permissions".

Answer (score 1):

You can reference this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=VS.90).aspx

You need the "Manage Process Template" or "MANAGE_TEMPLATE" permissions.  It is found under the Server-Level Permissions section.

> Server-level permissions are not specific to a single project. Instead, they are set on a server-wide basis. You can set these permissions only for three categories of users:
>
> > Server-level users and groups, such as Team Foundation Administrators
> >
> > Project-level groups that have been added to the server-level on your Team Foundation server
> >
> > Custom groups you create and add to the server level

Comment: Edited to reference TFS 2008 as the OP asked for.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that's quite what I'm after.  It looks like Manage Process Template permissions allow for editing the whole project template, and are server wide.  I already have people who are not Server Administrators, but are Project Administrators who can edit the work item templates for the team projects that they administer.  I just wanted to find a way to provide this project-level permission without requiring that they be Project Admins.